# locate and display ROIs separately

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a black Image with some clearly separated from each other white areas. This white image areas I would like to locate and display them separately, in the smallest possible rectangular shape.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Threshold the image cv::threshold
2. Find contours cv::findcontours
3. Use cv::BoundingBox on each contour
4. Use ROI concept to catch each rectangle (area)

Comment: Thank you, point 1 to 3 are working. But I get it not, to display the individual areas separately.

Comment: In addition, I would like not to show bounding boxes which fall below a certain size.

Comment: for 4th point, u can do like this - cv::Mat cropped = srcImage(rect/roi);

Comment: If u still unable to understand thrn tell me i will post demo code.

Comment: Filtering is so easy: Just iterate on them and delete any rectangle with area less than a threshold if you want code comment